# script for focusing on a highlighted text

Tags: outlook, autohotkey

What is wrong with my script?

Context: Inbox folder of Outlook. I want to click (focus) just only one email (the one with the gray color), but my script *ALSO* "colors" all emails the are above it.  I'm not sure what is the matter.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
+F7::
    PixelSearch, Px, Py, 14,98,754,962, 0xE1E1E1, 3, Fast
    if ErrorLevel
    MsgBox, That color was not found in the specified region.
    else
    Click, %Px%, %Py%
    return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Have you used a window spy to check the actual color?

Comment: yes, BTW, I was unable to show my script correctly, can someone help out?

Comment: You forgot to put spaces before the second line to set it in code-mode.  I had to add a few words for the edit to be accepted by the system (if my edit gets approved).

Comment: Are you sure ahk is picking the colour from Outlook and not another program?

Comment: yes, I'm absolutely sure that the color is correctly searched... my doubt is regarding the rest...

Comment: Can you discern that the click is being made at all?  Does the error messagebox ever show?  Perhaps if all the mails are being coloured - are they by chance getting selected? (I'm throwing guesses, as I don't use Outlook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are oh, say, scrolling or moving the cursor around in the preview panel, and now you want to jump the cursor to that same email's entry in the mailbox listing.

If this be the case, then here is a possible solution for you:

Okay, so we know that by default, whatever message you are viewing in the preview pane should be the highlighted entry in the mailbox list.  That means all we have to do is to set focus to the mailbox list pane - when that pane receives focus, then the highlighted entry should be able to receive your immediate keyboard commands since it is already selected.

Therefore, all you need to do with your ahk script is create a hotkey that sets focus to the mailbox pane.  Use your window spy to spy the class of the mailbox pane and just set focus to it.  You shouldn't have to worry about colours at all.

Maybe something like this for Office 2010:

```
+F7::
    ControlFocus, SUPERGRID2, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
return
```

or, for Office 2013:

```
+f7::
    ControlFocus, OutlookGrid1, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
    if ErrorLevel
        MsgBox, You don't seem to be in context.
return
```

Or, instead of hacking the window, you could just push `ctrl+1` - Outlook has a built-in keyboard command to set focus to the mailbox list.

Comment: your last script answers my request, however what should I do in order to enable that hotkey (+F7) but only when my cursor is navigating at the preview pane of Outlook 2013? Is that possible?